# Как сделать редирект node js

Tags: node.js

Только учусь.
хочу когда при подключении к БД если есть ошибка то переадресовывало на определенный адрес.

Как правильно релаизовать

```
connection.connect(function(err){
if (err) {       

  if(err.code == "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR"){ //если ошибка что не существует БД
    app.redirect("/mysql/error");  
  };
}
else{
  console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
} });
```

Comment: app это у вас что?

Comment: Подключение к БД идет в момент запроса к серверу или в момент его запуска?

Comment: `const express = require("express");             // подключение express
const app = express();                          // создаем объект приложения`

Answer (score 0):

не знаю правильно ли я сделал но я вывел все в отдельный модуль по правилу MVC
и там уже все сделал.
примерно так выглядит

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");

exports.error = function(request, response){
    response.render("./MySQL/viewMySQL.hbs");          //отправка ответа
};

exports.connect = function(request, response){
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({     //строка подключения к БД
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        database: "usersdb",
        password: "123456@"
      });

    connection.connect(function(err){
        if (err) {        
            if(err.code == "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR"){ //если ошибка что не существует БД
                console.log("Error: connect to DB - not correct DataBase name");    //выводим в консоль сообщение что не верное имя БД
                response.redirect("/mysql/error");                                  //отправляем на страницу с описанием ошибки
            };
        }
        else{
            console.log("Connect to MySQL sever is succefull");
        }
    });  
};
```